# How to us the Countif and Countifs functions with VBA macro in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to figure out the Countfi and Countifs vba code for a week now and not successful. There are two criteria and two worksheets in the same workbook. i need to pull data from sheet2 and place it in a single cell on sheet1. I have searched the web for over a week now and no success in finding a code that would work. Does anyone have a simple way to complete this function? Any assistance is much appreciated.

Need to use a VBA code to for-loop through the range.

Range is B7:B40 on Sheet1 uses the Countif formula.
=COUNTIFS(Sheet2[Criteria1],A8,sheet2[Criteria2],"Yes")

A8 = the names of the induvial which needs sum of "yes" as number.

Criteria1 and Criteria2is on Sheet2.

Tried to split a cell to get the range, use a vlookup function with the countif and record a macro and set it as a range.

```
Sub CountIfsheet1()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")

End Sub
```

[image: countif pic]

Comment: Please share the layout of sheet1 and sheet2.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Replace the formula with values via VBA? What are `Criteria1` and `Criteria2`? Defined names referring to same-sized single-column ranges? The expression `Sheet2[Criteria1]` would reference the data in column `Criteria1` of table `sheet2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Call worksheet function with `Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs`
- On Sheet1: column B is populated with formula `COUNTIFS`, column C is populated with VBA

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CountIfsheet1()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
    lastRow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 7 To lastRow
        ws1.Cells(i, 3) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs( _
            ws2.Columns(1), ws1.Cells(i, 1), _
            ws2.Columns(2), "Yes")
    Next
End Sub
```

OR

- Load data table into an array

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CountIfsheet1()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim arrData
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
    arrData = ws2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long, iCnt As Long, j As Long
    lastRow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 7 To lastRow
        iCnt = 0
        For j = 2 To UBound(arrData)
            If arrData(j, 1) = ws1.Cells(i, 1) And arrData(j, 2) = "Yes" Then
                iCnt = iCnt + 1
            End If
        Next
        ws1.Cells(i, 3) = iCnt
    Next
End Sub
```

[image]

---

***Update:***

- Both tables are loaded into an array
- Columns index are defined as consts

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CountIfsheet2()
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, iCnt As Long, j As Long
    Dim RowCnt As Long, arrRes, arrData1
    Dim lastRow2 As Long, lastCol2 As Long, arrData2
    Dim iCol1 As Long, iCol2 As Long

    Const CRI_COL1 = "Criteria1" ' modify as needed
    Const CRI_COL2 = "Criteria2"
    Const CRI_VAL = "yes"
    Const NAME_COL = 1 ' Names col
    Const DATA_COL = 2 ' data1 col
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
    ' Get the size of usedrange
    lastRow2 = ws2.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    lastCol2 = ws2.Cells(1, ws2.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    arrData2 = ws2.Range("A1", ws2.Cells(lastRow2, lastCol2)).Value
    ' Locate CRI_COL1 and CRI_COL2
    For i = 1 To lastCol2
        If StrComp(arrData2(1, i), CRI_COL1, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then iCol1 = i
        If StrComp(arrData2(1, i), CRI_COL2, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then iCol2 = i
    Next
    If iCol1 * iCol2 = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Can not find " & CRI_COL1 & " or " & CRI_COL2
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ' Loop through each name
    RowCnt = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, NAME_COL).End(xlUp).Row - 1
    arrData1 = ws1.Cells(2, NAME_COL).Resize(RowCnt, 1).Value
    ReDim arrRes(1 To RowCnt, 0)
    For i = 1 To RowCnt
        iCnt = 0
        For j = 2 To UBound(arrData2)
            If arrData2(j, iCol1) = arrData1(i, 1) And _
                StrComp(arrData2(j, iCol2), CRI_VAL, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                iCnt = iCnt + 1
            End If
        Next
        ' Write output to cell
        arrRes(i, 0) = iCnt
    Next
    ws1.Cells(2, DATA_COL).Resize(RowCnt).Value = arrRes
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for the assistance. we are now getting somewhere.

Comment: thanks again taller! I tried both options and they now count correctly. do you happen to know or have a way to make the arrData (j, 1) And arrData(j, 2) a dynamic range, where 1 and 2 are not always the same every time I pull the data. For example, this time the name (1) will be in column 1 but next time the name might be in column 15. Same for the Yes column.

Comment: How to determine the cols' index? Are the header fixed (eg. they are Name and Status)?

Comment: I what to say Yes to the cols' index...if I'm tracking. To better explain I attached a picture of the both sheets in on the opening commit called "countif pic". Its a word document. otherwise I'll try to explain.

Comment: The Name is located at column A but does change from time to time to column O. Same  goes with the Age Over 65 Y/N column it may be in D or moves to AA column.

Comment: Now the row header names never change such as Name = "Name" and Age Over 65 = "Age Over 65"

Comment: Dang you are fast, I'll check this out and get back to you tomorrow, thanks again!

Comment: That is exactly what I was trying to figure out. Works perfectly! Thank you for your help taller.

Answer (score 0):

### VBA CountIfs (Two Criteria)

[image]

**Usage**

```vb
Sub CountByNameOver65()
    CountIfsTwoCriteria "Sheet2", "H2", "T", "Yes", "Sheet1", "A2", "B"
End Sub
```

**The Method**

```vb
Sub CountIfsTwoCriteria( _
        ByVal SourceSheetName As String, _
        ByVal SourceLookupFirstCell As String, _
        ByVal SourceCountColumn As String, _
        ByVal SourceCountString As String, _
        ByVal DestinationSheetName As String, _
        ByVal DestinationLookupFirstCell As String, _
        ByVal DestinationCountColumn As String, _
        Optional ByVal IfNotValid As Variant = Empty)

    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "CountIfs (Two Criteria)"

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code

    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SourceSheetName)
    Dim slrg As Range, srCount As Long
    With sws.Range(SourceLookupFirstCell)
        srCount = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1
        If srCount < 1 Then
            MsgBox "No data found in sheet """ & sws.Name & """!", _
                vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set slrg = .Resize(srCount)
    End With
    Dim scrg As Range: Set scrg = slrg.EntireRow.Columns(SourceCountColumn)
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(DestinationSheetName)
    Dim dlrg As Range, drCount As Long
    With dws.Range(DestinationLookupFirstCell)
        drCount = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1
        If drCount < 1 Then
            MsgBox "No data found in sheet """ & dws.Name & """!", _
                vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set dlrg = .Resize(drCount)
    End With
    
    Dim Data() As Variant:
    If drCount = 1 Then
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = dlrg.Value
    Else
        Data = dlrg.Value
    End If
    
    Dim dr As Long, dlVal As Variant, IsValid As Boolean
    
    With Application
        For dr = 1 To drCount
            dlVal = Data(dr, 1)
            If Not IsError(dlVal) Then
                If Len(dlVal) > 0 Then IsValid = True
            End If
            If IsValid Then
                IsValid = False
                Data(dr, 1) = .CountIfs(slrg, dlVal, scrg, SourceCountString)
            Else
                Data(dr, 1) = IfNotValid
            End If
        Next dr
    End With
    
    Dim dcrg As Range: Set dcrg = dlrg.EntireRow.Columns(DestinationCountColumn)
    
    dcrg.Value = Data

    MsgBox "Countifs successfully updated.", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE

End Sub
```